# Community login RestAPI oauth2

Tags: community, oauth2

I want to login a community user using rest api.

I already have the access_token, but how do I proceed?

Comment: You've access_token means you have already login to the system. Using access_token you can consume REST services.

Comment: Ok, I got access_token from my sandbox, but I can't login in my community. Do you know how can I do the login in my community and not in my sandbox?

Comment: Hope you want to consume services from the "Community" for that you need to get access_token and call services, assuming "community" is target system from your sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a couple of articles directly related to this. They mostly speak to Portals, but it's the same procedure for Communities. The article that really got this off the ground for me was published by Pat Patterson (@metadaddy) in 2013. One of the important points is that you must use a DE org or Production for this to work... something about certificates in Sandboxes. The other important takeaway is the login URL. It's got to point to your site like `https://mysite.secure.force.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=<your_client_id>&redirect_uri=<your_redirect_uri>`

[OAuth for Portal Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/02/oauth-for-portal-users.html)

The second article is in the Mobile SDK Development Guide. Again it's talking about Portal, but works with Community Users too.

[Portal Authentication Using OAuth 2.0 and Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/oauth_portal_force_com_sites.htm)